# Parse certain data using JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json, linq, paypal

I'm trying to parse a certain link from some JSON data I'm getting but I can't seem to do it? Here's some sample data (from PayPal API):

```
{"id":"PAY-3YA6562986829024GK2JH7UQ","intent":"sale","state":"created","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"12.00","currency":"USD"},"description":"creating a payment","related_resources":[]}],"create_time":"2016-01-10T15:59:14Z","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3YA6562986829024GK2JH7UQ","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-5CP140577W0453458","rel":"approval_url","method":"REDIRECT"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3YA6562986829024GK2JH7UQ/execute","rel":"execute","method":"POST"}]}
```

So I've tried to do the following:

```
    dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(createdPayment.ConvertToJson());
    string paymentURL = stuff.href;
    MessageBox.Show(paymentURL);
```

And I've also tried to use `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`and populate `stuff.links` into a `JAraay` and then pull the link via an index, with no luck. This method that I'm using doesn't give me an error, it just returns a blank string for me?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your "href" links are within your "links" property, you can access them like this:

```
        dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

        foreach (var item in stuff.links)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.href);
        }
```

EDIT: added example of getting a list of links

```
        dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        var links = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in stuff.links)
        {            
            links.Add((string)item.href);
        }
```

Comment: `Additional information: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)' has some invalid arguments` I don't think you meant item.href? I think you meant `item` ? In any case I tried both with the same error :(.

Comment: Hmm, try this then: MessageBox.Show((string)item.href); or this: MessageBox.Show(item.href.ToString()); The example I gave you worked for me in a console app. :)

Comment: Ok that works! It returns to me each href in the JSON string, now question how do I just get the 2nd one, or the [1] index? I tried to add it to a list with no luck?
`    List<string> hreflist = new List<string>();
                hreflist.Add((string)item.href);
                MessageBox.Show(hreflist[1]);`

It seems that [0] contains all three links listed in the JSON string? Thank you man!

Comment: No problem. I added another example where the links are put into a list, it works on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class which hold the values you want from the JSON string.

The class will look something like this:

```
public class Payer
{
    public string payment_method { get; set; }
}

public class Amount
{
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public Amount amount { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<object> related_resources { get; set; }
}

public class Link
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string rel { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string intent { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public Payer payer { get; set; }
    public List<Transaction> transactions { get; set; }
    public string create_time { get; set; }
    public List<Link> links { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will be able to do something like this (using Newtonsoft):

```
var object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstring);
```

You will then be able to iterate over the `List<Link> links` object and get the href value from there.

Comment: I tried to do this and then create a `List<Links> list = new List<<Links>()` and then proceeding to add `o` which is `var o= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Links>(createdPayment.ConvertToJson());` to the list and then try to do `MessageBox.Show(list[0].href);` and gave me a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

If you need parse data then you can simply try this example console app. And read more at [Newtonsoft api reference](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm).

```
class Program
{
    class HrefResult
    {
        public string Href { get; set; }
        public string Rel { get; set; }
        public string Method { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String createdPayment = @"{""id"":""PAY - 3YA6562986829024GK2JH7UQ"",""intent"":""sale"",""state"":""created"",""payer"":{""payment_method"":""paypal""},""transactions"":[{""amount"":{""total"":""12.00"",""currency"":""USD""},""description"":""creating a payment"",""related_resources"":[]}],""create_time"":""2016 - 01 - 10T15: 59:14Z"",""links"":[{""href"":""https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3YA6562986829024GK2JH7UQ"",""rel"":""self"",""method"":""GET""},{""href"":""https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-5CP140577W0453458"",""rel"":""approval_url"",""method"":""REDIRECT""},{""href"":""https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-3YA6562986829024GK2JH7UQ/execute"",""rel"":""execute"",""method"":""POST""}]}";

        JObject stuff = JObject.Parse(createdPayment);
        IList<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken> results = stuff["links"].Children().ToList();

        IList<HrefResult> hrefResults = new List<HrefResult>();
        foreach (JToken result in results)
        {
            HrefResult hrefResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HrefResult>(result.ToString());
            hrefResults.Add(hrefResult);
        }

        foreach(var elem in hrefResults) Console.WriteLine("{0}", elem.Href);
    }
}
```